# Is there a function to replace vanishing values with 0 while logical indexing?

Tags: r

I would like to know whether there is a fast solution for my problem.

I simplified the problem to a minimal case, e.g.:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

b <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
```

If I calculate `a[b]` I receive: `[1] 1, 2, 4`

But I'd like to have: `[1] 1, 2, 0, 4, 0` , replacing the `3` and `5` with `0`'s.

Since my dataset is huge I urgently need to avoid a `for`-loop but I have no idea.

Thanks in advance!
Elmo

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50844942/4137985

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If b is true then a else 0 `ifelse(b,a,0)`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Great answer! Love it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` to replace the positions, here given by `!b`, with `0`.

```
replace(a, !b, 0)
#[1] 1 2 0 4 0
```

or using `[<-`

```
`[<-`(a, !b, 0)
#[1] 1 2 0 4 0
```